How to assess the absolute strength of a correlation between two multifactorial variables when some of their factors are negatively correlated
I have two multifactorial constructs, one of which consists of 5 subfactors, and the other 4. I am looking to evaluate the 'absolute' strength of the association between the two constructs.
The issue is that when the model is constructed in the standard way (CFA), it appears that the positive and the negative interrelationships amongst the subfactors average out the relationship of the construct at the global level to about zero. However, there are significant relationships at the factorial level!
construct1 =~ subfactor1a + subfactor1b + subfactor1c + subfactor1d + subfactor1e
construct2 =~ subfactor2a + subfactor2b + subfactor2c + subfactor2d
construct1 ~~ construct2




CorrTable
1a
1b
1c
1d
2a
2b
2c
2d
2e




1a
1










1b
.50
1









1c
.45
.50
1








1d
.60
.50
.45
1







1e
.55
.45
.45
.55
1






2a
-.10
-.20
-.15
-.09
-.11
1





2b
-.20
-.05
-.10
-.10
-.01
.57
1




2c
-.05
-.02
-.09
-.01
-.05
.65
.55
1



2d
.05
.01
.05
.05
.03
.55
.55
.55
1



What is the best way to assess the 'absolute' strength of the relationship amongst the two variables while avoiding this averaging to zero of the effects when viewed altogether?
I have attempted to reverse-score the first three subfactors of the second construct, but this did not change the strength of the association between the two constructs.
Thank you in advance!

Isn’t this exactly what canonical correlation describes?

I don't really understand the question. You want to correlate two factors in a CFA - why is this a problem? Loadings being positive and negative don't cancel each other out. Looking at the correlation matrix, the two factors don't appear to be particularly highly correlated.

Please clarify what you mean by "positive and the negative interrelationships amongst the subfactors average out".  It appears you are only referring to the cross-item correlations...and this should not be the focus of your analysis if the research intends to focus on the constructs (the items measure the construct...thus, once you have the construct, the items become far less meaningful individually...if the model fits the data).

Hi all, thank you for your comments @JeremyMiles; @GreggH. When I create a CFA correlating the two factors, the correlation is low between them. However, some of the intercorrelations (rather than the loadings) amongst the subfactors of the two constructs are negative, while others are positive. Because some of those interrelations are negative and some positive, overall the relationship between the 2 factors appears to be weak. What I want to do is find a way to aggregate the strengths of the subfactors interrelationships without reducing the overall strength of the relationship b/w them.

@Dave: Looking into canonical correlations, thank you for the tip

These non-zero correlations would be reflected in lack of model fit and high modification indices, and the majority of them are trivially small.

What is your sample size?

@JeremyMiles - thank you for following up. The model fit (two constructs composed of their respective factors and correlated with one another) indeed is high (CFI = .97, TLI = .96, RMSEA = .06, SRMR = .03). MIs reveal some cross-loadings (MI>100) but not much, agreed. The sample size is about 11000.

I think your conclusion that they average out to zero is correct. Some are high, some are low.  But some share slightly more with the other construct than others - one reason to use multiple item scales is so that this happens.

@JeremyMiles Is there any way to aggregate them without making them not average out to zero?

I can't think of one. You want the factor loadings to be subservient to the correlations, and you can't do that (unless you just ignore the factors but that defeats the purpose of doing CFA).

Maybe if you fit a single factor model, and then consider the composite reliability to be the equivalent to the correlation, that might work? Except that the model will have horrible fit, because it's wrong.

I am open to the possibility that a CFA is not the right approach at all. I have found vague rumors of other types of correlations (non-Pearson) that do not have a negative/positive polarity but nothing I could make any sense of

First, there are some issues with the terminology used here.  The constructs are measured by items (not sub-factors; a sub-factor is a 2nd order factor analysis, where 2nd-level latent factors are measured by 1st-level latent factors, which in turn are measured by their corresponding latent variables).
As for a CFA conducted in the “standard way”...this would suggest that a confirmatory factor analysis model was run with the model assumption that there is no correlation between the two factors (e.g., the factors are orthogonal).  Thus, the estimation is going to try to fit a model that essentially has no correlation between the cross-factor items.  And, this is what appears to be happening in the output provided.
It is possible to run a CFA where there is a non-zero correlation estimated between  the two latent factors.  In this case, the cross-factor item correlations can be estimated from the model as
$$r_{ij} = \lambda_i · \hat\rho · \lambda_j$$
where $\lambda$ is the standardized item factor loading and the $\hat\rho$ is the estimated correlation between the factors.  These are usually rather low values...again, this is what appears in the lower 4x5 submatrix of your correlations.
Assuming these values are all from a population with zero correlation, some positive and negative small values would be expected.
I do not know if this answers your question, but I do hope it clarifies the scenario for others visiting this post at a later time.

Hi Gregg, thank you for your answer. Here is the dummy code for the CFA as I did it :
model <- '
Construct1 =~ F1 + F2 + F3 + F4 + F5
Construct2 =~ F6 + F7 + F8 + F9
Construct1 ~~ Construct2
'
The issue is that some of the factor correlations (across constructs) are negative and some positive (e.g., F1 & F6 = -.10; F1 & F7 = +.10). Therefore, on the global level the correlation appears to be about zero. The question is to how to treat the negative and the positive correlations as absolute strength to avoid this.
Hopefully this helps clarify the situation!

Neither of the positive or negative correlations for the cross-factor items are statistically (meaningfully) different from zero.

But they are! I fuzzed the numbers a little bit for data privacy reasons, but in my case, I am seeing all but 4 (16/20) as statistically significant at p < .05.

That probably is a sample size issue.  But, to be clear, these are estimates for a model that ¿is or is not? including a correlation between the factors.

The sample size is about 11,000 and the cross-factor correlations were included using just a correlation matrix amongst all 9 of the component items

@bjovnyryk - I think I've created a dataset with 9 factors (say F1 to F9) reproducing the correlation table you provided in your question. Now in the first comment you say F1 & F6 = -.10, F1 & F7 = +.10. I can't relate this to anything in the correlation table. Am I misunderstanding something?

(p.s. I get the correlation between the two constructs numerically to -0.089)
